# Error -32601 received from application: Method not found

Tags: flutter

I'm getting error in this code. Any help?

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './homepage.dart';
void main() => (MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Chat",
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

In HomePage.dart file

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Chat"
        ),
      
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In Debug Console it shows:
Restarted application in 2,271ms.
Error -32601 received from application: Method not found
Reloaded 0 of 496 libraries in 237ms

Comment: You need to provide more information, like the relevant code, error logs, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue *is* with your code. Your syntax for the main method doesn't make sense for running a flutter app. You likely intended to call `runApp` on the widget within `main`.

Changed main:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './homepage.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Chat",
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
`
```